# How to customize Solution Explorer toolbar in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to remove some buttons from the Solution Explorer toolbar in Visual Studio 2012, but I am not able to find that toolbar in the list when I go to Tools --> Customize.

Can someone tell me where to find the customization options for this toolbar?

Answer (score 6):

Rearranging of the commands in the Solution Explorer toolbar is not supported (like the main toolbar).